# How do I know which script in running Chrome causes to open a new pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have installed an extension in Chrome which opens up a pop-up tab when I click anywhere on the page (even if there is no link). When I see the "sources" tab in the "Developer Tools", it has a *lot of extra scripts* (like more than a hundred different scripts from hundreds of different sources) loaded which are never present in the original web page. I am trying to find out what particular script causes this. How do I do this?

Here's what I have already tried:

- I tried adding breakpoint on "mousedown" event listener. Turns out there are a couple of scripts adding event listener on that so I can't say which particular script is that.
- I also tried go through the `div` and `iframe` that have attributes like `height: 0, left: 0` or `top: -999, left: -999` but there are multiple such `div`s.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding window.open:

```
window.open = function () { debugger; }
```

or

```
window.open = function () { console.trace(); }
```

Comment: I tried to put the above command in Chrome console (on any web page but before the pop-up tab opens) but it doesn't retun anything. Could you please tell me if I am doing some thing wrong?

Comment: The extension might be using the window.open function in other frame or it might be keeping a reference to the open function. In the first scenario, you can try and override the function in each frame, by changing the frame with the frames combo in the top area of the Console (you'll see something like <top frame>, click there to change the frame).